# Alternative to 'interval' date syntax for IBM solidDB

Tags: sql, date, syntax, intervals

For a research project, I'm using IBM's solidDB to run some test queries on. The dataset I'm using is the TPC-H dataset, so using the queries that come with it seems like a logical choice. 8 out the 19 queries, however, use SQL-92's date interval syntax:

```
select
    l_returnflag,
    l_linestatus,
    sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,
    sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,
    sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as sum_disc_price,
    sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) * (1 + l_tax)) as sum_charge,
    avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty,
    avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
    avg(l_discount) as avg_disc,
    count(*) as count_order
from
    lineitem
where
    l_shipdate <= date '1998-12-01' - interval ':1' day (3)
group by
    l_returnflag,
    l_linestatus
order by
    l_returnflag,
    l_linestatus;
```

The :1 in there is filled by the query generator as a number. According to the solid [IBM solidDB SQL Guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CBkQFjAB&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.software.ibm.com%2Fsoftware%2Fdata%2Fsoliddb%2Finfo%2F6.5%2Fman%2FSQLGuide.pdf&rct=j&q=ibm%20soliddb%20sql%20guide&ei=mdyATb-JOY2LhQepmsWxBw&usg=AFQjCNHEHJFUjr6EFxEfOnAvmzlN7RtwPQ&cad=rja), solidDB doesn't support the interval keyword.

In order to use the query templates provided with the TPC-H benchmark, I need some sort of alternative syntax to use as for substracting days from a date and the like. The [TIMESTAMPADD](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.programmer.doc/doc/s0005327.time.and.date.functions.html) didn't seem to do much either, so I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: Do you have an example of the failed TIMESTAMPADD attempt?

Comment: Seems like TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, -1, NOW()) should work.

Comment: I tried "l_shipdate <= TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY, -90, '1998-12-01')", but solid tells me SQL_TSI_DAY is not a column name. The example on the page uses it as part of the select part of a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on solidDB, but the link you gave has this syntax...

```
SELECT NAME, {fn
TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_YEAR, 1,
HIRE_DATE)} FROM
EMPLOYEES
```

Try putting the {fn } around your function call?

Comment: I can hardly believe that actually seems to have worked; what an odd way to do this. The TPC-H query generator removes it tho, but thats a different problem. Thanks for the obvious hint...

Answer (score 1):

the scalar functions with some examples are listed in [the Programmer guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.programmer.doc/doc/s0005024.appendix.scalar.functions.html). In version 7.0, you can also write external functions, and procedures with C if there's something missing. More info can be found from SQLGuide > SQL Reference

if you have any questions regarding to solidDB, feel free to post them also to [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1310) .

Cheers, Vilho Raatikka